# Restricted profile can't unlock tablet in android 10

Tags: samsung, tablet, android-10, restricted-profiles, samsung-galaxy-tab-a

On a Samsung SM-T290 (Galaxy Tab A 8.0") with Android 10, there is regular user account and also a restricted profile for users to use in order to restrict what apps can be used.

In previous versions of android, the restricted profile could unlock the tablet. However, in android 10, I can't seem to switch to the restricted profile user on the lock screen, unless the regular user account unlocks it first.

Is there a way to allow the restricted user account to unlock the tablet, so the main user doesn't have to login/unlock it first?

Comment: As far as I know there is no other way. The primary user have to log in to unlock the encrypted files. On previous Android versions Full Disc Encryption was used and entering the password as part of the boot process was mandatory. Now the decryption is bound to the primary user first login.

Comment: Ah, bingo--that was it. Once I disabled encryption, the restricted user could unlock the tablet. In this case, file encryption isn't necessary. Settings > security > other security settings, turn off "strong protection". Thanks!

Comment: Yes! Thank you!