# Can't access phone as forgotten work profile password

Tags: password, profiles, samsung-galaxy-s-10, restricted-profiles

A while back I set a password for my work profile. For the life of me I cannot remember it (tried so many different combos).

I want to access my phone but it's asking for the password, which I don't know. I tried quite a few times and it eventually said if I input the wrong password again my work profile would be deleted. This would be fine as I could gain access to my personal account and set up my work profile again.... but no, after inputting another incorrect password, it just says try again in 30 seconds.

I can't even access my personal account as it's just asking for the password.

I don't want to go "nuclear" option to factory reset my phone as not all my data is backed up.

Is there anything else I can do to gain access to my phone?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232182